# Check if excec terminated

Tags: c

I'm trying to recreate the background functionality from shell.

In my code `bg = 1` if the command want's to be executed on background.

What I want is the normal behavior of shell where if I call:

```
prompt$ pwd &
```

I get:

```
[pid] 
/path
prompt$
```

The problem is that with my code:

```
if (*bg == 1)
    {
        bgpid = fork();

        if (bgpid == -1)
        {
            perror("Error: fork");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (bgpid == 0)
        {
            printf("[%d]\n",getpid());
            execvp(mandato[0], mandato) //This is the command
            perror("Error: Execvp");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I get the prompt before the result of the exec:

```
[pid] 
prompt$ /path
```

I understand that this happens because, since I'm not using wait, the prompt is displaying before the result of the exec.

Any ideas on how fix this?

Comment: There's nothing to fix.  If you want the process to run in the background, you must let it.  Whether the shell or the background process writes to the terminal first is an inherent race condition that you do not want to address here.  "Solving" the race condition by having the parent wait for the child defeats the purpose of running the child in the background.

Comment: That's the thing, adding a wait defeats the purpose as you say, yet I need the expected output, have you any idea on how to do it?

Comment: What you describe shouldn't really be "expected".   Real shells don't guarantee any particular order, and you will often see the child's output after the prompt if it takes longer to execute.  It might be a little less likely on real shells because they do more work to generate a fancy prompt, check if you have mail, and so on, giving the child just a little more time to finish.  But overall it is just chance.